# Getting ID with no Incomplete Status in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these data below to play with, and I want to pull only the ID/s with no Incomplete or 'I' status.

```
ID  SUBJECT   STATUS
1   Math        C
1   Physics     C
1   Chemistry   I
2   Math        I
2   Physics     C
2   Chemistry   I
3   Math        C
3   Physics     C
3   Chemistry   C
```

How do you code this in SQL wherein only ID #3 gets pulled since it is the only one without 'I' in its status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use "NOT IN"

```
select id 
    from tablename 
    where id NOT IN (select id from tablename where STATUS = 'I')
```

Comment: gald i could help

Comment: Because of the semantics of `NOT IN ` (it returns no rows if any values returned by the subquery are `NULL`), either of the other two answers are actually better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select * 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table where id = t.id and STATUS = 'I');
```

You can also re-express this as by using `group by`:

```
select id 
from table
group by id
having count(distinct STATUS) = 1 and
       sum(case when STATUS <> 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this,

```
SELECT id
  FROM tablename
 GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(status) = MAX(status)
   AND MIN(status) = 'C';
/
```